# space is not working with this regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have problem with this regular expression.

For example I want to check this name `maikal rabie`. I will get false because i have space between the two words. What I need is checking for real name with at least 3 characters.

```
$Name = 'maikal rabie';
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/', $Name)) {                    
    // Do something false
}
```

Comment: Treasure hunt: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info (Hint: You search for: `whitespace` for your character class)

Comment: You're also not capturing spaces in your regex, so of course it'll return false.

Comment: but i tried to add /s/ but the code didnt work

Comment: Refer to my answer below, I reworked your Regex

Comment: Would `John O'Reily-O'Niel IV` be a `real name`? Your current regex says your string may only have `A-Za-z` and must be atleast 3 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

You're not looking for whitespaces in your regex, so of course it'll return false. Also remember names (full names) could be more than 2 names, and they can also contain special characters.

Here's a simple Regex that I built off of yours, and captures whitespaces and common characters found in names, as well as allows for multiple names, in case someone has multiple first-middle-last names

```
([A-Za-z\s-_']{3,}){2,}
```

And all 3 of these names work with this regex

```
maikal rabie
D'Arcy Gordon
Michael Jones-Hartman
```

So now instead of checking for false, you can check for true

```
$Name = 'maikal rabie';
if(preg_match('/^([A-Za-z\s-_\']{3,}){2,}$/', $Name)) {                    
     // Do something true
}
```

Comment: there is ' missing in you code but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Since you're using single quotes in the preg_match function, the ' in the regex should have been escaped. I fixed the code above, so it works now.